# Can someone help me give a proof for this?

Tags: proof-writing

I know there are theorems about integrals of odd and even functions, but i kept wondering about integrals that share symmetry around an axis $x=c$. I've been trying to give a proof for this but can't seem to get around it; could someone help me prove/disprove this?

$$
\large \int_{c-x}^{c+x}f(x)dx=2\int_{c}^{c+x}f(x)dx
$$

Hypothesis--------------------

$$
\large f(c-x)=f(c+x)
$$

$f(x)$ is symmetric around $x=c$ for all $x$

Comment: Hint: make a substitution. The function $f(x-c)$ is even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two initial remarks:

1. For clarity, you should not use the same letter in the limits of integragion and as the integration variable itself.
2. I assume your hypothesis is that, for all $x$, $f(c-x)=f(c+x)$.

Let us prove that 
$$
\large \int_{c-x}^{c+x}f(t)dt=2\int_{c}^{c+x}f(t)dt
$$

Proof: 
First, let us consider:
$$ \int_{c-x}^{c}f(t)dt$$
Let $s=2c-t$, then we have: $t=2c-s$, $dt=-ds$ and
$$ \int_{c-x}^{c}f(t)dt=-\int_{c+x}^{c}f(2c-s)ds=\int_{c}^{c+x}f(c+(c-s))ds=\int_{c}^{c+x}f(s)ds$$
In the last step above, we used the hypothesis to concluded that $f(c+(c-s))=f(c-(c-s))=f(s)$.

Now we have 
$$
\int_{c-x}^{c+x}f(t)dt=\int_{c-x}^{c}f(t)dt + \int_{c}^{c+x}f(t)dt=\int_{c}^{c+x}f(s)ds+ \int_{c}^{c+x}f(t)dt=2\int_{c}^{c+x}f(t)dt
$$

Comment: Shouldn't the integration limits change after the substitution is done?

Comment: @zickens They  change.  Note that $t=c-x$ corresponds to $s=2c-(c-x)=c+x$ and $t=c$ correspponds to $s=2c-c=c$.

Comment: got it! didn't see it originally; thank you!